# Stackable Modifications in Scala

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

As per the Programming in Scala book:
If there is following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class IntQueue
Class BasicIntQueue extends IntQueue
trait Doubling extends IntQueue
trait Incrementing extends IntQueue
trait Filtering extends IntQueue
```

for the object

```
val obj=new BasicIntQueue with Doubling with Incrementing
```

the linearization would be

```
BasicIntQueue->Incrementing->Doubling->IntQueue->AnyRef->Any
```

but as per the book:
When any of these classes and traits invoke a method via super the implementation invoked will be the first implementation to its right in the linearization.

So as per my understanding an overridden method put() present in all mixins and classes would be called in the following order:
Incrementing->Doubling

How then the method put() of BasicIntQueue class gets called when it is not to the right of the Doubling in linearization.

Does this mean the object's class (BasicInQueue in the ex)'s method will always be called after the hierarchy methods are called.

Answer (score 3):

Your linearization is incorrect, because you forgot to take into account the anonymous class that you create where you instantiate `obj`. You code is equivalent to

```
class ObjClass extends BasicIntQueue with Doubling with Incrementing
val obj = new ObjClass
```

and the linearization of that class is

```
ObjClass->Incrementing->Doubling->BasicIntQueue-> IntQueue->AnyRef->Any
```

which solves your problem.